# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor<?>' available when I use ContextHierarchy

Tags: java, spring

I want to cache context with database in SpringBootTest.

When try two ContextConfiguration in ContextHierarchy:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {DatabaseTestConfiguration.class}),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {OverridingTestConfiguration.class}),
})
public class MyTest {
    // test methods
}
```

I get Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor<?>' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:343)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1123)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setApplicationContext(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:374)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:708)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
... 85 more
```

When I union ContextConfiguration in ContextHierarchy:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = {DatabaseTestConfiguration.class, OverridingTestConfiguration.class}),
})
public class MyTest {
    // test methods
}
```

Context cache with extra OverridingTestConfiguration.

Could anybody give any idea what wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and that got resolved once I added @EnableWebSecurity annotation. Try that